# Console printing backwards

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the code to print the name of a class and then greetings on the same line. For example:

```
(DriveThru): Hi, welcome to Starbucks! What can I get started for you?
```

Here's my code:

```
module Order
  def order_drink
    "(#{self.class.name}): #{self.greeting}"
  end
end

class Lobby
  include Order
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def greeting
    puts "Hi, welcome to Starbucks! How are you doing today #{self.name}?"
  end
end

class DriveThru
  include Order
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def greeting
    puts "Hi, welcome to Starbucks! What can I get started for you #{self.name}?"
  end
end

dt = DriveThru.new("Tom")
lb = Lobby.new("Jessica")

puts dt.order_drink
puts lb.order_drink
```

When I run the code, it prints the greeting first, line breaks, then prints the class name like this:

```
"Hi, welcome to Starbucks! What can I get started for you?"
(DriveThru):
```

What am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `greeting` function is executing the `puts` statement. Due to the way Ruby (and most other programming languages) works, the `order_drink` method will evaluate the contents of the `greeting` method (calling a `puts` statement) first before returning its own value.

Dropping the `puts` at the beginning of each `greeting` function, for example:

```
class Lobby
  include Order
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def greeting
    "Hi, welcome to Starbucks! How are you doing today #{self.name}?"
  end
end
```

This will cause your script to output the following:

```
(DriveThru): Hi, welcome to Starbucks! What can I get started for you Tom?
(Lobby): Hi, welcome to Starbucks! How are you doing today Jessica?
```

That said, it'd be preferable to add an `attr_reader` for the greeting attribute, and set its value in the `initialize` method (also known as the constructor), like so:

```
class Lobby
  include Order
  attr_reader :name, :greeting
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @greeting = "Hi, welcome to Starbucks! How are you doing today #{name}?"
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for elaborating everything as well. Helpful for noobies like me.